# How to re render react hook function component when redux store change?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-hooks

I have a function component `UpdateCustomerScreen` connect with `redux store` and use `react-navigation` navigate to `SelectorGenderScreen`.

`selectedCustomer` is my `redux store` data. I change the data on `SelectorGenderScreen`, when I use `navigation.pop()` to `UpdateCustomerScreen`. I have no idea how to re render the `UpdateCustomerScreen`.

Here is my `UpdateCustomerScreen`:

```
const UpdateCustomerScreen = ({ navigation, selectedCustomer }) => {

  const gender = changeGenderOption(selectedCustomer.sex); // gender is an array.

  const [sex, setSex] = useState(gender); // set array to my state.

  console.log('sex', sex);

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.push('SelectorGenderScreen')}
        <Text>Navigate to next screen</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity> 
    </View>
  );

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { selectedCustomer } = state.CustomerRedux;

  return { selectedCustomer };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(UpdateCustomerScreen);
```

Here is my `SelectorGenderScreen`:

```
const SelectorGenderScreen = ({ navigation, selectedCustomer, changeGender }) => {

  const gender = changeGenderOption(selectedCustomer.sex);

  const [genderOption, setGenderOption] = useState(gender);

  return (
    <Header 
      title={Translate.chooseStore} 
      leftComponent={
        <BackButton onPress={() => navigation.pop()} />
      }
    />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeGender(selectedCustomer, genderOption)}>
      <Text>Change the redux store data</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { selectedCustomer } = state.CustomerRedux;

  return { selectedCustomer };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    changeGender: (selectedCustomer, genderOption) => {
      dispatch(changeGender(selectedCustomer, genderOption));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SelectorGenderScreen);
```

I try to use `useCallback()` in `UpdateCustomerScreen`. When I  `navigation.pop()`, It still doesn't re render.

```
// my state
const [sex, setSex] = useState(gender);

// It is not working
useCallback(() => {
  console.log(sex);
},[sex]);

// It is not working
console.log('sex', sex);

return (
  // my view
);
```

Any way to re render the `UpdateCustomerScreen` when redux store value has been changed ?

Comment: check out: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#hooks

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, can you tell me which api funcion is the key point ?